# How can I use a ::placeholder font-size variable with Styled Components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, font-size, placeholder

My goal is to have responsive font-size in a <textarea> element, for both the user **input text** and the **placeholder text**. I am using Styled Components in React with Typescript.

I have achieved responsive font-size for the **input text** , but the same script does not affect the **placeholder text** .

```
const DynamicTextInput = styled.textarea.attrs((props: {
    fontSize: string}) => props)`
        font-size: ${(props) => props.fontSize};
        &::placeholder {
            font-size: ${(props) => props.fontSize};
        }
`;

const placeholderText = 'Hello Placeholder!...';  
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
const newFontSize = 140 - (count/4) + 'px';

<DynamicTextInput
    placeholder={placeholderText}
    onChange={e => setCount(e.target.value.length)}
    fontSize={newFontSize}
    />
```

*note: the placeholder text itself needs to be a variable.*

Can you see how I can get the **placeholder text** font-size to respond to the same variable that is successfully manipulating the **input text** font-size?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to make this:

```
    export const DynamicTextInput = styled.textarea.attrs({
      placeholderTextColor: "red"
    });
```

or just remove `&` from `&::placeholder`

```
const DynamicTextInput = styled.textarea.attrs((props: {
    fontSize: string}) => props)`
        font-size: ${(props) => props.fontSize};
        ::placeholder { // changed
            font-size: ${fontSize}; // changed
        }
`;
```

Comment: Thank you for engaging, Jay. Strangely, I have found that manipulating the colour as you have suggested works fine, but the font-size doesn't - with my newFontSize calculation

Comment: please dont use `${(props) => props.fontSize` just use `${fontSize}`

Comment: @edwindharris just use `fontSize` because you are destructuring props

Comment: I’ve made your suggested amendment and tried a few variations, but I still can’t get it cooking. I’ll keep trying and let you know if I have a breakthrough. Thank you again for your time 

Comment: Sure, please do upvote if this helps

Comment: Hi Jay, unfortunately I have not yet been able to get it going. I will let you know if I make progress. Thank you again.